# memory error while extending lists

Tags: python, list, extend

I have such a list:

```
mylist=[[[1,2,3,...,200],[1,2,3,...,200],[1,2,3,...,200],[1,2,3,...,40]],...]
```

I want to merge the first three lists in each item in mylist and have something like this:

```
final_list=[[[1,2,3,...,600],[1,2,3,...,40]],...]
```

I have written this code to do that:

```
def extend(mylist):
    a=mylist[0]
    b=mylist[1]
    c=mylist[2]
    a.extend(b)
    a.extend(c)
    return a

final_list=[]
for i in mylist:
    final_list.append([extend(i),i[3]])
```

it works properly when the lists are small, but when I want to merge three 200-array lists into a 600-array list, I face "MemorryError":

```
    a.extend(c)
MemoryError
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Buy more RAM? ;)

Comment: You should try to use generators with yield, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure this is gonna work.

I created your list using a [`generator`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) to avoid having all your lists in memory. And using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to improve efficiency while concatenating your sublists.

```
import itertools

mylist = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]]

def contact_elements(huge_list):
  for i in huge_list:
    yield [list(itertools.chain(i[0], i[1], i[2])), i[3]]

final_list = [sub for sub in contact_elements(mylist)]
print(final_list) # [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]]
```